Selected Text Replacement Bug UITextView Mac Catalyst
Starting with the macOS version 14.x.x and TextKit1, selecting multiple lines of text triggers a text replacement bug: some of the text on one of the selected lines inadvertently replaces a portion of the selected text.
For example, the bug is exhibited when selecting the following lines:
Carnaroli, Maratelli, or Vialone Nano are best
Vialone Nano cooks quickly – watch it! It also absorbs condiments nicely.
Avoid Baldo, Originario, Ribe and Roma

To trigger the bug, select the three line paragraph using either the cursor or shift with arrow keys. Notice that a portion of the selected text was replaced. Command-Z to undo will allow you to repeat the undesired behavior.
In this case, "e Nano cooks quickly - " is replaced by "Baldo, Originario, Ribe."
This does not occur with all strings or selected strings, but in cases where it does occur, it is perfectly reproducible. It does not occur on iOS. Pasteboard contents are irrelevant. After triggering the bug repeatedly, at some point it stops occurring.
Why does this bug occur? How can it be fixed?
Screen grabs showcasing the behavior
Before selection:

After selection:

Sample code to recreate the issue
@interface TestNoteViewController ()

@end


@implementation TestNoteViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    [self createTextView];
}

- (void)createTextView {
    
    NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.note.text
                                                                     attributes:nil];
    
    NSTextStorage *textStorage = [NSTextStorage new];
    [textStorage appendAttributedString:attrString];
    
    CGRect newTextViewRect = self.view.bounds;
    
    // Create the layout manager
    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [NSLayoutManager new];
    [textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];
    
    // Create a text container
    NSTextContainer *container = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(newTextViewRect.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
    [layoutManager addTextContainer:container];
    
    
    // Create and place a text view
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:newTextViewRect
                                               textContainer:container];
    [self.view addSubview:textView];
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    UILayoutGuide *safeArea = textView.superview.safeAreaLayoutGuide;
    [textView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:safeArea.leadingAnchor].active = YES;
    [textView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:safeArea.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
    [textView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:safeArea.topAnchor].active = YES;
    [textView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:textView.superview.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
}

@end

Sample code to recreate the issue WITHOUT the text container and layout manager, which also exhibits the bug
@interface TestNoteViewController ()

@end


@implementation TestNoteViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    [self createTextView];
}

- (void)createTextView {
    
    UITextView *textView = [UITextView new];
    textView.text = self.note.text;
    [self.view addSubview:textView];
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    UILayoutGuide *safeArea = textView.superview.safeAreaLayoutGuide;
    [textView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:safeArea.leadingAnchor].active = YES;
    [textView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:safeArea.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
    [textView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:safeArea.topAnchor].active = YES;
    [textView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:textView.superview.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
}

@end


Does this issue appear if you create a normal UITextView without setting up your own text container for it?

Yes, the issue still occurs with just a normal text view added to the view hierarchy, with setting the text container and layout manager. I'll edit the question to include this mode of re-recreating the issue.

I can't reproduce your issue. I created a new project, put your second set of code in the supplied view controller, and built it for Mac Catalyst. In the code I set the text view's text property to the three lines of text mentioned in your question. Running the app on an M3 MacBook Pro with macOS 14.4.1 resulted in no issues when highlighting the text.

I can't reproduce your issue either, and this is just a hunch but does the actual text get replaced, or is it only the visual feedback? In the latest macOS update Apple fixed a ton of weird layout issues in TextKit 1 compatibility mode, some of which sometimes caused glitches like this. The actual text value did get replaced, though.

The actual text value is replaced. Interesting that others are unable to reproduce the issue (and zero customer feedback reporting the issue). I'm on M3 MacBook Pro running 14.4, I'll see if other devices are exhibiting the bug.
